# How to copy files from exact folder which is positioned somewhere in a folder structure using gulp

Tags: javascript, npm, gulp

I'm wondering is there a way to solve this problem:

I would like to copy all fonts from bower_components to **.tmp/assets/fonts**, but the problem is that some fonts are .svg, so if I do it in a regular way using this code:

```
gulp.task('copyBowerFonts', function(){
 return gulp.src("bower_components/**/*.{ttf,woff,eof,svg}")
            .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.tmpFonts));
});
```

... i will get all font files along with .svg files, so the mentioned peace of code will also copy images with .svg extension and put them into the **.tmp/assets/fonts** . So if i could say ok, copy everything from fonts/ within any folder to the desired location it would be great.

I will also use  **[gulp-flatten](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-flatten)** to copy just files without their folder structure.

So, finally, is there an option like, or how could this work?:

`gulp.src("bower_components/**/fonts/*.{ttf,woff,eof,svg}"`

I assume that solution is simple, but I couldn't find it so far.

Thanks for the help. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern you wrote should work for you.

Keep in mind that Gulp uses [glob module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob):

- `*` Matches 0 or more characters in a single path portion
- `**` If a "globstar" is alone in a path portion, then it matches zero or more directories and subdirectories searching for matches. It does not crawl symlinked directories.

Comment: you were right. It works.
I was using the path inside an array, so that was a problem in my case.
So I put it as I wrote it here. 
Thanks!